# What is the logic behind the sentence "Sieh es dir an"

Tags: grammatical-case, idiom

When you say "look at it" in German, why do people use the expression "Sieh es dir an"? What is the grammar logic of using "dir" here?

Comment: Edited the *ihn* to *es*, which would be the context-free translation of *it*. It looks like you want to focus on the usage of *dir*, so it's better to avoid confusion about other parts of the sentence.

Comment: Relaxed: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11984/anschauen-as-reflexive-or-not

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a slight difference between `etwas ansehen` and `sich etwas ansehen`. The difference is that the reflexive version (sich etwas ansehen) is used to emphasize on the activeness of the looking. There is looking, and there is looking with attention and care.

To make an example: "Are you looking at the picture?"

> Siehst du das Bild an?
>   Siehst du dir das Bild an?

The first question asks if you are facing the picture, or more accurately whether your eyeballs are directed at the picture. The second question asks if you are looking at it actively, with care. (you cannot enjoy art before you *inspect* it. I have *seen* the Mona Lisa before, but I havent *really looked at it* yet.)

Comment: Or: »I have *looked* at the Mona Lisa, but I haven't really *seen* it.«? The emphasis adds so much meaning in your example that I'm not sure it wouldn't work either way.

Comment: You might *look at* (ansehen) a wall of firebrick because it's the only thing tight in front of your hotel window, but you'll probably never *watch* or *study* (sich ansehen) it. The key difference is the *intent to learn something* about the object.

Comment: @Philipp in German, that sentence doesn't work **either way**, as the difference between the two meanings really isn't that big, and it would sound really strange saying "Ich habe die Mona Lisa angesehen aber ich habe sie mir noch nie angesehen". It just.. doesn't work

Comment: I believe a similar effect could be created by adding the word *wirklich*. But it depends on the context, maybe more than in the English sentence, I'll give you that.

Answer (score 6):

The logic (actually, the grammar) is that the infinite form of the verb is *sich etw. ansehen*, which is a reflexive verb and *dir* is the conjugated form (2nd person singular) in dative case of the reflexive pronoun *sich*. *sich etw. ansehen* is a so-called "proper reflexive verb" ("echtes reflexives Verb") here and it is demanding dative case for the reflexive pronoun, because the verb itself is demanding an object in accusative case already ("Wen/Was sehe ich mir an?" - "Es").

Answer (score 1):

Schalgend wird der Beitrag des reflexiven Partikels bei "Ich sehe mir Deinen Bandscheibenvorfall an" vs. "Ich sehe Dir Deinen Bandscheibenvorfall an".

The contribution of the reflexive particle in "I look at your herniated disc" vs. "By looking at you, I see your herniated disc" becomes sonic.

Bei "sieh es an" vs. "sieh es Dir an" könnte das erste auch eine Aufforderung sein, nur in die Richtung zu schauen, ohne auch den Geist darauf zu lenken, etwa ein Modell beim Fotografieren, welches ein Objekt anschaut.

Comment: I guess, adding the information that _jemandem etwas ansehen_ has the meaning: _to recognize something in looking at somebody_ would make this post less confusing for non-germans.